# Google map problem when hide and then toggle

Tags: jquery, google-maps, slidetoggle

I have a google map in my page. I set a button with

```
.slideToggle()
```

functionality to show/hide the  with the map and it do so.
The problem is that I want to hide the map by default.
If I use the display:none on the css, than after toggle up (show) the map,
I don't see the markers that I put in it. Also, the map area seems much smaller than the area of its div.
All of this doesn't happen if I load the page showing the map (display:block).

How can I start with hiding the map, and still be able to see it after toggle it?

Answer (score 2):

For others who still have this problem on api v3 use `google.maps.event.trigger(your_map_name, 'resize');` which is equivalent to checkResize() method from api v2.

Answer (score 1):

Your Google maps initialization should be in a function, if it's not make sure it is.
Then you can only initialize the map after you toggle it, this will also make sure it doesn't get loaded if the user doesn't wish to see it.

```
function init_maps(){

    // google maps api goes here

}

var init = false;

$('.show_map').click(){

    if(!init){

        init_maps();
        init = true;

    }

    $('.map').slideToggle();

}
```

Comment: I still have the problem of the map area seems much smaller than the area of its div. And it isn't matter if I first toggle and than init the map or otherwise. The <div> definition is:
~<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 922px; height: 380px"></div>~

Comment: Without additional code it's pretty hard to figure out why that is happening.